# Combining BeautifulSoup and json into one output

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have probably not explained my question well but as this is new to me... Anyway, I need to combine these two pieces of code.

I can get the BS working, but it uses the wrong image. To get the right fields and the right image, I have to parse the json part of the website and therefore BS won't work.

## The json parsing here

```
import json
import urllib
import requests
import re

r    = urllib.urlopen('https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=10000&page=1')
data = json.loads(r.read().decode('utf-8'))

for post in data['posts']:
    print post['episodeNumber']
    print post['title']
    print post['audioSource']
    print post['image']['medium']
    print post['content']
```

## And replace the try / BS part here:

```
def get_playable_podcast(soup):
"""
@param: parsed html page            
"""
subjects = []

for content in soup.find_all('item'):

    try:        
        link = content.find('enclosure')
        link = link.get('url')
        print "\n\nLink: ", link

        title = content.find('title')
        title = title.get_text()

        desc = content.find('itunes:subtitle')
        desc = desc.get_text()

        thumbnail = content.find('itunes:image')
        thumbnail = thumbnail.get('href')

    except AttributeError:
        continue

    item = {
            'url': link,
            'title': title,
            'desc': desc,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail
    }

subjects.append(item)

return subjects

def compile_playable_podcast(playable_podcast):
    """
    @para: list containing dict of key/values pairs for playable podcasts
    """
    items = []

    for podcast in playable_podcast:
        items.append({
            'label': podcast['title'],
            'thumbnail': podcast['thumbnail'],
            'path': podcast['url'],
            'info': podcast['desc'],
            'is_playable': True,
    })

    return items
```

I have tried all sorts of variations with passing through the output to the items section, but the most common error I get is. I just have no idea how to pass the data from the json through.

```
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>
Error Contents: name 'title' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../addon.py", line 6, in <module>
from resources.lib import thisiscriminal    
File "....resources/lib/thisiscriminal.py", line 132, in <module>
'title': title,
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you your expected output should be for the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON request should contain all the information you need. You should print `json_data` and take a look at what is returned and decide which parts you need.

Based on what your other code was looking for, the following code shows how you could extract some of the fields:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=10000&page=1')
json_data = r.json()
items = []

for post in json_data['posts']:
    items.append([
        post['title'].encode('utf-8'), 
        post['image']['thumb'],
        post['excerpt']['long'],
        post['permalink'],
        ])

for item in items:
    print item
```

This would give you output starting:

```
['Stowaway', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Stowaway_art-150x150.png', u'One day in 1969, Paulette Cooper decided to see what she could get away with.', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/episode-118-stowaway-7-5-2019/']
['The Lake', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Lake_art-150x150.png', u'Amanda Hamm and her boyfriend Maurice LaGrone drove to Clinton Lake one night in 2003. The next day, DeWitt County Sheriff Roger Massey told a local newspaper, \u201cWe don\u2019t want to blow this up into something that it\u2019s not. But on the other side, we\u2019ve got three children...', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/episode-117-the-lake-6-21-2019/']
['Jessica and the Bunny Ranch', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Bunny_art-150x150.png', u'In our\xa0last episode\xa0we spoke Cecilia Gentili, a trans Latina who worked for many years as an undocumented sex worker. Today, we get two more views of sex work in America. We speak with a high-end escort in New York City, and take a trip to one of the...', u'https://thisiscriminal.com/episode-116-jessica-and-the-bunny-ranch-6-7-2019/']
```